# LaTex code on Firefox

Tags: 20.04, firefox, latex, html

I am currently attending a Machine Learing course on Coursera. There are video lectures and some reading material. On the webpages of the reading material there are some formulas written in LaTeX, but in the boxes where I should see the formulas, I see only the LaTeX code. So it looks like Firefox doesn't compile it. This is weird, because on other websites (such as Wikipedia) I don't have this problem.

The browser I am using is Firefox and I am using Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS.

Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT** If I open [this webpage](https://www.intmath.com/cg5/katex-mathjax-comparison.php?processor=MathJax) (as suggested in an answer) I do see the equations. So I wonder if it is an issue of Coursera. Also, whenever I use Coursera with Chrome, I don't have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The firefox by itself is MathML-[capable](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/MathML), but not LaTeX.

The LaTeX in usually visualized by JavaScript libraries like MathJax or KaTeX. See [comparison as example](https://www.intmath.com/cg5/katex-mathjax-comparison.php?processor=MathJax). If you see equations on this page then your browser have loaded JavaScript libraries and executed their code normally.

You have to check that JavaScript is enabled on your Firefox and that it loaded all js-files fully and successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes, I do see equations on the webage that you linked. 
I don't understand.. maybe is the coursera website which has a problem?

Comment: Funny enough, if use Chrome, instead, then I don't have this issue..